# Thor::Group do not continue if a condition is not met

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm converting a generator over from RubiGen and would like to make it so the group of tasks in Thor::Group does not complete if a condition isn't met.

The RubiGen generator looked something like this:

```
 def initialize(runtime_args, runtime_options = {})
   super
   usage if args.size != 2
   @name = args.shift
   @site_name=args.shift
   check_if_site_exists
   extract_options
 end

def check_if_site_exists
  unless File.directory?(File.join(destination_root,'lib','sites',site_name.underscore))
    $stderr.puts "******No such site #{site_name} exists.******"
   usage
  end
 end
```

So it'd show a usage banner and exit out if the site hadn't been generated yet.

What is the best way to recreate this using thor?

This is my task.

```
class Page < Thor::Group 
include Thor::Actions
source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

argument :name
argument :site_name
argument :subtype, :optional => true


def create_page
  check_if_site_exists
  page_path = File.join('lib', 'sites', "#{site_name}")
  template('page.tt', "#{page_path}/pages/#{name.underscore}_page.rb")
end

def create_spec 
    base_spec_path = File.join('spec', 'isolation', "#{site_name}")
        if subtype.nil? 
            spec_path = base_spec_path
        else 
            spec_path = File.join("#{base_spec_path}", 'isolation')
        end

        template('functional_page_spec.tt', "#{spec_path}/#{name.underscore}_page_spec.rb")

end

protected 

 def check_if_site_exists # :nodoc:
      $stderr.puts "#{site_name} does not exist." unless File.directory?(File.join(destination_root,'lib','sites', site_name.underscore))
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

after looking through the generators for the spree gem i added a method first that checks for the site and then exits with code 1 if the site is not found after spitting out an error message to the console. The code looks something like this:

```
def check_if_site_exists 
  unless File.directory?(path/to/site) 
     say "site does not exist." 
     exit 1
  end
end
```